# Laravel Eloquent mapping data with relationship

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent, relation

I have an eloquent query with a relation but I get ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id' of shop->id.

```
    $collection = Lead::with('shop');
    $collection = $collection->orderBy('data', 'DESC');
    $collection = $collection->get();
    
        $json = $collection->map(function ($contact) {
                    return [ 
                     'id' => $contact->id,
                     'name' => $contact->name,
                     'shop' => [
                        'id' => $contact->shop->id,
                        'name' => $contact->shop->name
                      ],
                ];
        });

 return response()->json(['contacts' => $json], 200);
```

Is there any way to use eloquent mapping with relation?

Comment: Does every single Lead in your database definitely have a shop?

Comment: @Djave sometimes not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Laravel's helper method:
[`optional()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-optional)

> The `optional` function accepts any argument and allows you to access
> properties or call methods on that object. If the given object is
> `null`, properties and methods will return `null` instead of causing an
> error:

Instead of:

```php
// ...
                        'id' => $contact->shop->id,
                        'name' => $contact->shop->name
// ...
```

Use this:

```php
// ...
                        'id' => optional($contact->shop)->id, ✅
                        'name' => optional($contact->shop)->name ✅
// ...
```

Comment: I had used a ternary operator like this: $ contact->shop_info? $contact->shop_info->id: ''; but your solution is a lot better! thanks!